# How to extract elements based on condition they contains a specific element?

Tags: python

I'd like to extract all `href` from item list that also contains `class="list-item__pay-count"`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

res = requests.get("https://browse.gmarket.co.kr/search?keyword=%ec%95%84%ec%9d%b4%ed%8f%b013&f=is:cb")
html = res.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

item_containers = soup.select(".box__information")
for item_container in item_containers :
    dev = item_container.select_one("div.box__information-score > ul")
    if dev == ".list-item__pay-count" :
        print('=====END=====')
```

Every item is encapsulated in a div with class .box__information and has an `<a>`.

Some of the items has lists with `class="list-item__pay-count"` at the bottom of `class="list__score"` - Only these items `href` I try to scrape.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to achieve?

Select the elements in the way you just described it using `css selectors`:

```
soup.select(".box__information:has(li.list-item__pay-count) a.link__item")
```

To get its `href` iterate over your resultset in my example it is done by a `list comprehension`:

```
[a['href'] for a in soup.select(".box__information:has(li.list-item__pay-count) a.link__item")]
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

res = requests.get("https://browse.gmarket.co.kr/search?keyword=%ec%95%84%ec%9d%b4%ed%8f%b013&f=is:cb")
html = res.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

links = [a['href'] for a in soup.select(".box__information:has(li.list-item__pay-count) a.link__item")]
print(links)
```

#### Output

```
['http://item.gmarket.co.kr/Item?goodscode=2254643676', 'http://item.gmarket.co.kr/Item?goodscode=2228429131', 'http://item.gmarket.co.kr/Item?goodscode=2263151456', 'http://item.gmarket.co.kr/Item?goodscode=1692990699', 'http://item.gmarket.co.kr/Item?goodscode=2226064416', 'http://item.gmarket.co.kr/Item?goodscode=2230415843', 'http://item.gmarket.co.kr/Item?goodscode=2230418646', 'http://item.gmarket.co.kr/Item?goodscode=2230419179', 'http://item.gmarket.co.kr/Item?goodscode=2230419987', 'http://item.gmarket.co.kr/Item?goodscode=2230420445', 'http://item.gmarket.co.kr/Item?goodscode=2230420983', 'http://item.gmarket.co.kr/Item?goodscode=2233580653', 'http://item.gmarket.co.kr/Item?goodscode=2320507863', 'http://item.gmarket.co.kr/Item?goodscode=2226051594']
```